# Remove SQL Server user, change owner on any schema/job first

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm asked to remove users from a bunch of SQL servers and wondering how i can take the follow code the next step further by also first switching ownership of schemas and jobs to the account 'master' to facilitate the delete

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; 
    DECLARE @Tsql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @Tsql = ''''

    SELECT @Tsql = ''DROP USER '' + d.name
    FROM sys.database_principals d
    JOIN master.sys.server_principals s
        ON s.sid = d.sid
    WHERE s.name = ''deleteme''

    EXEC (@Tsql)
'
GO
```

Am I missing something aside from schema and jobs to ensure the account can be deleted without errors?

I ran a command

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; 
    DECLARE @Tsql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @Tsql = ''''

    SELECT @Tsql = ''DROP USER '' + d.name
    FROM sys.database_principals d
    JOIN master.sys.server_principals s
        ON s.sid = d.sid
    WHERE s.name = ''deleteme''

    EXEC (@Tsql)
'
GO
```

and also

```
select s.name as schema_name, 
    s.schema_id,
    u.name as schema_owner
from sys.schemas s
    inner join sys.sysusers u
        on u.uid = s.principal_id
where u.issqluser = 1
    and u.name not in ('sys', 'guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA')
```

But unsure how to link the two for the end goal.

Comment: Schemas are owned by users (which are database level), but jobs are owned by logins (server level) so what are you dealing with, a user or a login? Or both?

Comment: You also have to take into account ownership of many other securables, such as databases and database objects, see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-manage-jobs-by-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Charlieface Hello there. I am dealing with both. I suppose I'll have to change ownership of all schemas then delete the database level user then change ownership of all databases, ect. before I can delete server level user. Right now I try deleting, see an error, and so drill down to each schema and find the one owned by the user, its tedious and I know there's a better way.